# missing extensions (Mathematica Link)

Tags: netlogo

How would I diagnose why an instance of NetLogo started with Mathematica Link cannot find extensions that ship with NetLogo?  (It may (?) be relevant that instead of "installing" `NetLogo.m`, I `Get` it directly.)  The link is otherwise working fine, only the extensions are not found.

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the NetLogo User Manual for Mathematica Link (see `http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/mathematica.html`) under known issues following entry can be found :

- > If a model loaded with the NetLogo-Mathematica link uses a NetLogo
  >   extension, the extension must be located in the same directory as the
  >   model itself. If the extension is located in NetLogo's
  >   application-wide extensions directory, it will not be found.